# Define a bean of java.io.FileInputStream in Spring makes the Struts2 stream result not work

Tags: java, spring, struts2, autowired, fileinputstream

We are using the Struts2 with spring in a project.

Consider a simple action with **stream** result

```
@Action(value = "sample-export", 
        results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "stream", params = {
        "inputName", "exportInputStream", "contentType",
        "${exportContentType}; charset=UTF-8", "Content-Disposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"${filename}\"", "contentDisposition",
        "attachment; filename=\"${filename}\"", "bufferSize", "2048" }) })
public String export() throws ClientException {
    //buildExportInputStream() creates and returns new ByteArrayOutputStream by using jasper
    exportInputStream = buildExportInputStream();
    LOG.debug("Exporting to {} file ", getFilename());

    return SUCCESS;

}
```

This works fine.

Something strange happens when I add below line in `spring-applicaiton-context.xml` !!

```
  <bean id="sampleStream" class="java.io.FileInputStream" >
        <constructor-arg  value="c:/sample.jks"/>  
  </bean>
```

After adding above line the `inputStream` of action will be a zero size file! When I set a break point in **StreamResult**,  **doExecute** method the `inputStream.read(oBuff)` is always **-1**.

---

The created bean (**sampleStream**) will be referenced by other beans by using ref for example `<ref bean="sampleStream"/>`. When I change this structure and use **sampleStream** as an inline parameter it works fine:

```
<bean id="anotherBean" class="foo.bar">
        <bean class="org.xml.sax.InputSource">
            <constructor-arg index="0" >
                    <bean class="java.io.FileInputStream">
                        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="c:/sample.jks"/>
                    </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Or this will also fix it:

```
<bean id="sampleStream" class="java.io.FileInputStream" autowire-candidate="false">
            <constructor-arg  value="c:/sample.jks"/> 
  </bean>
```

---

Well can you help me to find what is going wrong ?! Why defining a bean of `FileInputStream` will cause this happens ?!

### Updated

I have found that the `sampleStream` will be autowired to `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult` and I see this log:

```
DEBUG ort.DefaultListableBeanFactory Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'sampleStream'
DEBUG ort.DefaultListableBeanFactory Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult' via constructor to bean named 'sampleStream'
```

This mistaken autowired is the source of problem ! Is there any workaround. And by the way, why the `sampleStream` is autowired here !

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-4559

Comment: Beans are singletons. An InputStream can only be read once. You're making a bean of type InputStream. So, as soon as one piece of code reads from the stream, all the other ones won't be able to read anymore. Not to mention the problem if two actions try to read concurrently from the stream. Why don't you just create a **new** InputStream, read from it, and close it, every time you need it?

Comment: Thanks! But The bean which is defined in spring ("sampleStream" ) is different from the bean which is used in the action.  The `buildExportInputStream()` always returns a new `ByteArrayOutputStream`. This is the thing which surprised me, the "sampleBean" is not used in any actions at all ! Am I missing something :(

Comment: There should be class cast exception, and reading from the stream is performed by the result, not you.

Comment: Thanks, but I did not see cast exceptions, and we are not dealing with stream I just mentioned what happens when I set breakpoints there. As I mentioned every think works fine. We face error when we add a bean of input stream to spring !

Comment: Have you changed spring autowire strategy to type?

Comment: Do you mean something like `<bean id="sampleStream" class="java.io.FileInputStream" autowire="byType">` ?!

Comment: Something like `struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire`.

Comment: The structure of my project did not let me test it right now, with this change I get some errors an the project is not start :(  Well, at https://struts.apache.org/docs/spring-plugin.html I found that the default **autowire** type is **name**. On the other hand as mentioned in the question, the generated log says a type autowiring is happening that `Autowiring by type from bean name ...` do you think it will resolve ?! By the way can you please explain why this **autowiring** happens the bean Id is **sampleStream** and it should not be autowired !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Struts2 Spring object factory by default will try to determine the best strategy for autowiring components, which is legacy behavior by the way.

With this behavior an instance of `StreamResult` is created with `StreamResult(InputStream in)` constructor and Spring will try to inject constructor arguments as well.

To avoid this set `struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect` constant to `true` in your struts.xml file.

```xml
<constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire.alwaysRespect" value="true" />
```

This will ensure that the autowire strategy is always respected. (Default is by name.)